# How to send context to wizard and add reference from Form in Odoo 13

Tags: odoo

so I Have several fields in my Wizard model that the default value is the same from the form but we can change it. I try to send my form field value using context but it has an error like this

> odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: ": "name
>   'arrival_date' is not defined"

while evaluating. The name of the field already right because when I use context in my line or one2many field It works just fine.

And Second when I create the record its not referencing my form record. Do I need to change the default write method?

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="kre_product_reservation_wizard_form_view">
        <field name="name">kre.product_reservation.form</field>
        <field name="model">kre.product_reservation</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Add Attendees">
                <group>
                    <group>
                        <!-- Add your fields here -->
                        <field name="reservation_number"/>
                        <field name="arrivals_date"/>
                        <field name="departure_date"/>
                        <field name="stay_period"/>
                        <field name="qty"/>
                        <field name="price"/>
                        <field name="tax"/>
                        <field name="sub_amount"/>
                        <field name="tax_amount"/>
                        <field name="amount"/>
                        <field name="description"/>
                    </group>
                    <notebook>
                        <page string="Guest List">
                            <field name="guests"/>
                        </page>
                    </notebook>
                </group>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>

    <act_window id="insert_reservation_wizard" name="Insert Reservation" context="{'reservation_id' : active_id, 'arrival_date' : arrival_date, 'departure_date' : departure_date}" binding_model="kre.reservation" res_model="kre.product_reservation" view_mode="form" target="new"/>
```

And this is the binding model Field that I want to send in Context.

```
<field name="name"/>
<field name="billing_name"/>
<field name="arrival_date"/>
<field name="departure_date"/>
<field name="group"/>
<field name="currency"/>
<field name="sub_total"/>
<field name="tax"/>
<field name="total"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hello Theodorus Agum Gumilang,

On your `act_window` you can set the model id or any selection or boolean from the default context passing. Like this,

```
<act_window id="insert_reservation_wizard"
        name="Insert Reservation"
        binding_model="kre.reservation"
        res_model="kre.product_reservation"
        view_mode="form"
        context="{'default_reservation_id' : active_id, 'reservation_id' : active_id}"
        target="new"/>
```

You can check the other reference on odoo for default value set from act_window. As on your default value set from the form itself on wizard view, you can do with by changing the approach this way,

**1) Calling your wizard action from the python.**

**2) On the python, you can pass the default value on context.**

On you **form** view added the **button**,

```
<button name="action_wizard" string="Your String" type="object" class="btn-primary" />
```

On Python Function,

```
def action_wizard(self):
    return {
        'name': _("Your String"),
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'res_model': 'Object',
        'view_id': self.env.ref('module.ref_id').id,
        'target': 'new',
        'context': {
            'default_name': self.default_name,
            'default_billing_name': self.default_billing_name,
            'default_arrival_date': self.default_arrival_date,
            'default_departure_date': self.default_departure_date,
            'default_group': self.default_group,
            'default_currency': self.default_currency,
            'default_sub_total': self.default_sub_total,
            'default_tax': self.default_tax,
            'default_total': self.default_total
        }}
```

Thanks